# Interact with a drawing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script that operates some functionality(coping rows, parsing rows and cells, changing format and then inserting into new range) . I assigned the script to a drawing, so when I click a drawing(button) it calls the function.

But the only problem that I am now facing is when a user accidentally or on purpose   intensively clicks the button twice or more, a function does not work properly because every calling takes some time (about 5 seconds) and a next call of the function operates the wrong range.

So as i know there is no way to call the function asynchronously, is there?

So I need to somehow interact with the button to either disable button once after it clicked and then enable again when it's finished.

Hope i explained it correctly.

```js
// the function is called by drawind from a spreadsheet

function addNewWeek() {


    // here is some logic that copies, parses and inserts cells (takes about 5 seconds) 

    // need to wait for finish of the function

}
```

this button calls the function

[image: the button calls the function]

Answer (score 0):

Class Sheet has the method [getImages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getImages()) that returns all over-the-grid images on the sheet. I think that it could be used to get the drawing, then use [assignScript(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#assignScript(String)) to change the assigned function.

Related

- [Resize all images after an edit in google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54653664/1595451)
- [Deleting images in Google sheet via script error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52602177/1595451)